# How can achieve RPO RTO of 15 minutes and 30 minutes respectively between two diffrent siesmic zone DC locations whcih are 1000 kms apart

Tags: business-process-management

I want RPO of 15 mins and RTO of 30 mins between my DC and DR location which are 1000 Kms apart. Application is Linux based and Databases are PostgressDB, SQL amd NoSQL databases etc. Total Data size will be 1PB and daily rate of data change will be 20-50 GB per day.

Looking for a solution, tools, and process to achieve the same with fall-in and fall-back procedures.

Comment: First your question isn't about code so this does not fit here. Also asking for tools isn't part of this site. Please get started on your own. Feel free to ask again with a concrete technical question to one library. This is also more suitable for an other subsitze